# get value from query array of id's ruby

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, iteration

I've been scouring, looking for the answer to this and have quickly killed 3 hrs.

I'm doing a query to get certain user_id's from the database. ( I do it this way so I can persist the result in a variable for use later in requests )

```
sql = <<-SQL
    SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE users.active = 't' and (users.created_by = #{user_id} OR users.id = #{user_id})
SQL
connection.execute(sql)
```

I then have an array of ID's. So I'm now attempting to iterate these to see if a particular ID is in this array.

the variable

```
raise @editable_users_list.to_yaml
```

the result

```
- !binary "aWQ=": 7
  0: 7
- !binary "aWQ=": 8
  0: 8
- !binary "aWQ=": 10
  0: 10
```

My hopeless attempt to extract the correct result

```
def can_edit_user?
      if logged_in?
        @editable_users_list.each do |user|
          raise user.to_s
          if user[:id].to_s == current_user[:id].to_s
            return true
          end
        end
      end
      return false
    end
```

The raise exception above reveals my query is in fact an array of arrays

```
{"id"=>7, 0=>7}
```

Now I've been playing around with alot of things mentioned [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html) and have just given up.

Any and all help for this...muchly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only the id of user then simply do  it like :

```
@editable_users_list.map!(&:id)
```

and check it like :

```
return @editable_users_list.include? @editable_users_list
```

**EDITED** :

```
sql = <<-SQL
    SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE users.active = 't' and (users.created_by = #{user_id} OR users.id = #{user_id})
SQL
@editable_users_list = connection.execute(sql)

@editable_users_list = @editable_users_list.map!(&:id)
```

Comment: I'm getting errors, surely from the way I'm trying to implement your solution.  Could you provide this in a code block together please?  To test your block you could use the same query above, just remove the conditionals.

Comment: both block arg and actual block given.

Comment: I get 'undefined method id for {"id"=>7, 0=>7}:Hash' when I do this      `def can_edit_user?
      if logged_in?
        raise @editable_users_list.map!(&:id)`

Comment: Why you are using the SQL connection instead of Active Record ? Also can you show mw the response of your 'sql' .

Comment: Exactly the same error when I do it. but I've figured it out, yet want to give you credit for persisting with this.

Comment: what is the output of @editable_users_list = connection.execute(sql)

Comment: The error I get is `undefined method `id' for {"id"=>5, 0=>5}:Hash`

Comment: Oh yeh,  I'm using SQL connection because I need the Id's found and set on every request. So the plan was/is to do it this way as I don't require a full object as what ActiveRecord would give me.  Happy to hear your thoughts on this one as well.   Cheers again

Comment: Dude ... take a look on the Active Record tutorial ... If you need just an id ... then user User.all(:select=>"id").map(&:id)

Comment: Still, I read somewhere that if you have a heavily used query and don't require an object, then SQL connection is the go, performance wise.

Comment: I'll change to using ActiveRecord though I think.  Cause it has caching which is definately better in my case.  Thanks again Vik

Answer (score 0):

The answer is below and it's due to the fact that the SQL is returning a hash of hashes.  Got Absolutely No Idea Why.  If someone would be so kind as to tell me the above queries, both mine and Vik's are returning this, that would be Huge :).  Though I digress.

What got it working was to loop through both hashs like so

```
def can_edit_user?(user_id)
  if logged_in?
    @editable_users_list.each do |user|
      user.each do |id,value|
        if value == user_id
          return true
        end
      end
    end
  end
  return false
end
```

I'm not sure if this is the way it should be done, or if this is a workaround to a 'SQL connection' problem.

Anyways, the above code it doing what I want it to do, just not as optimal (hell, maybe the whole lot is not optimal...)

Cheers again Vik for taking the time and your thoughts on the above would still be great.